# Does it make sense to have more #replicas than #broker in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am going to use kafka as messaging system. Still missing the following dots in my mind.

1. How many brokers can I have on one machine ?
2. Does it make sense to have more #replicas (partition replication) than #broker in kafka ?
3. Is it possible to add additional zookeeper server(on other machine) to scale without shutting down/restarting the current service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* have more than one broker per machine but there is usually not any good reason to have more than one.

I can not think of a good reason to have more #replicas specified than #brokers.

Your Zookeeper servers should optimally be on separate machines and be and odd number of nodes. There is a tradeoff between write latency and resiliency here. 3 Zookeepers are common where write latency is very important. 5 or even 7 nodes can be used for more resiliency.

Comment: To add to (2): You will actually run into problems when #replicas > #brokers because Kafka will then always consider its partitions to be under-replicated (by your prior assumption), which basically makes Kafka think "There's a serious risk of data loss, help me fix this situation!" (that is, your Kafka cluster has then entered the equivalent of a yellow WARN state).